# How to change wordpress query_posts by clicking a link with ajax inside post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i want to changes query_posts by clicking a link witch ajax and load new result in to my div

i use this code in single.php

By using the $_GET function at the top

```
        if( !empty($_GET['key']) ) 
                 $meta_key=$_GET['key'];
            else $meta_key= ''; // default
```

dropdown list

```
<form action="" method="get">
<select name="key" id="fromchange" class="style-select"onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">

<option value="">""</option>
<option value="artist_artist" <?php if ($key == "artist_artist") { echo 'style="color:gray" selected'; } ?>> ACTOR</option>
<option value="artist_director" <?php if ($key == "artist_director") { echo 'style="color:gray" selected'; } ?>> DIRECTOR</option>

</select>
</form>
```

phpcode and div for new result is :

```
<div id="result">
            <?php // ACTORS
    $title1='>'. get_the_title() .'</a> ('.get_field('date').')';
    $title2='>'. get_the_title() . ' ('.get_field('date').')'; 

    $args_actor=array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'cat' => '5',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    );

     $crew_query = null;
     $crew_query = new WP_Query(array($args_actor,
     'meta_query'=> array('relation' => 'OR',
     array('key'=>$meta_key,'value'=> $title1,'compare'=>'LIKE'),
     array('key'=>$meta_key,'value'=> $title2,'compare' => 'LIKE'))
     ));
     if( $crew_query->have_posts() ) {
     echo'<ul class="mpanel">';
     while ($crew_query->have_posts()) : $crew_query->the_post(); 
     include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-movie/content-list-movie-crew.php'); 
     endwhile;echo '</ul>';}
     else{
         echo'<ul class="mpanel">';
         include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-movie/movie-crew-else.php');
         echo '</ul>';
     }

    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    ?>
            </div>
```

how to run this code and change query by click with ajax in div ?